# How to load, save, and show array to list?

Tags: java, android, arrays, gson

I have XML layout like this:

```
[....textedit....][addbutton]

=======list1=========

=======list2=========

=======list3=========

=======list4=========
```

What to do if I want to **Load** and **Show** the list onCreate from **SharePreferences**, be able to **Add** "item" to the list, and **save** it to **SharedPreferences**? Any extra simple beginner explanation are welcome since I'm a total newb.

My code below is a big mess, and I got it 100% from stitching from one example to another example that I got from anywhere.

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.Context;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String FileName = "myFile";
    Button BtnSave;
    EditText editName;
    ListView lv;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        BtnSave = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        BtnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    saveFile();
                }
            });
        
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,empty);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        //Setting onClickListener on ListView
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item Clicked: "+i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        editName =  findViewById(R.id.edit1);
    }
    
    private void saveFile() {
        String strName = editName.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(FileName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("name", strName);
        editor.commit();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Data Saved Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help you.

```
fun addProduct(productsItem: Product) {

    sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences(TAG,Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    var gson=Gson()
    var cartProduct=getAllProducts()
    cartProduct.add(productsItem)
    var json=gson.toJson(cartProduct)
    println(json)


    sharedPreferences.edit().putString("cart_products",json).apply()

}

 fun getAllProducts(): ArrayList<Product?> {
    sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences(TAG,Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val listType =
        object : TypeToken<List<Product?>?>() {}.type

    var productsItemList:ArrayList<Product?> = ArrayList();
    val json=sharedPreferences.getString("cart_products",null)

    if (json !=null){
        var gson=Gson()
        productsItemList=gson.fromJson(json,listType)


    }



    return productsItemList

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to compile it tomorrow.

Comment: So, for the addProduct(productsItem: Product){...I change it to Button onClick? As for the "product", can I change it to getText(editText)?

Comment: sorry bro, im not sure wether the java codes you provided is intended for android java or not, it seems very different and has many problems in compiling. the structures are bit odd.

Comment: yes bro,you can change in button click  or other actions, product just a parameter you can change the parameter as you need(String,int,List,ArrayList etc).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you need to:
1)input some word in EditText
2) show it in ListView
3) save it to preferences
right?

I think you must do next steps:

1. Create `private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();`
2. When you input something in EditText and clicked on button, call `list.add(editName.getText.toString());` and then call saveFile and save `list.toString();`
3. When you need to load file, create function

```
private void loadFile() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(FileName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String string = sharedPref.getString("name", "");
    ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(string.split(", ")));
}
```

4. Load in adapter your newList.

Comment: On first load, the list is just blank, because it is empty. After typing something on the edittext and press "add" button, it is suppose to store the array string in preference and show it on listview, or show it first then save. And next time the app load, it will shows 1 data on the list.

Comment: Also, if you are free, please provide the full code because I'm lack of java experience. As I mentioned above, the code I provided is from many web provided examples stitched together.